# Do-While don't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, do-while

I have some problem with WHILE, idk why.

```
do {
        url = find[o['random'].random(0, find.length)];
        sliced4 = url.slice(url.length-4,url.length);
        sliced5 = url.slice(url.length-5,url.length);
        c++;
        console.log(c+' '+sliced4+'-'+sliced5);
        if (c > 5) {
            o['bot'].send('Похоже, таких изображений не существует.', o['body'], {});
            return;
        }
    } while(sliced4 !== '.jpg' || sliced4 !== '.png' || sliced5 !== '.jpeg');
```

find[] contain links to images from Google.Images

Result from console(it's mean that code must working, because sliced4 == '.jpg'):

[image: result]

Comment: Simple answer: `||` should be `&&`

Comment: BTW, you can get the last 4 characters with `url.substr(-4)`.

Comment: @Barmar 3:21 on my clock, forget about this, ty.
Also, ty with my question. C:

Comment: Don't feel too bad. This is one of the most common mistakes made by new programmers. We see it in dozens of questions every day.

Comment: A nicer way to check for your url extensions at the end -> `} while(['jpg','png','jpeg'].indexOf(a.split('.').slice(-1)[0]) >= 0))`